# How to create multiple user's on Domino Server without actually configuring physicaly on it?

Tags: lotus-domino

I have made an application which is reading domino server mailboxes and saving it on another location.

I am able to read and access all mailboxes.
Now to test product i want to create about 100 to 200 user's.
I am able to create user's but but in order to add mails,calendar e.t.c.
I need to physically configure user on machine then creating all items.

Is there any other alternative? Which allow me to add mails or other data into these nsf files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the RegisterNewUser in NotesRegistration class

Here is the documentation --> http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/7604e322d563f2618525704a0040ee80?OpenDocument

Comment: i am getting :

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {60434CA9-132A-11D5-B14F-00C04F79D784} failed due to the following error: 80040154.


For "NotesRegistration".

Comment: How are you creating the NotesRegistration object?  For COM you have to create it using the session.CreateRegistration() method.  Post code if possible.

Comment: thanx Carlos. I was creating Notes Registration Object as:

NotesRegistration obj_reg = new NotesRegistration ();